# XML Schema: Multiple indicators within a complexType

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

The xsd snippet below states the XML element 'Warrior' should have three attributes, 'Strength', 'Sword' and 'Axe'.

```
<complexType name="Warrior">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="Character">
      <sequence>
        <attribute name="Strength" type="integer"/>
        <attribute name="Sword" type="weapon"/>
        <attribute name="Axe" type="weapon"/>
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

How do I define a 'Warrior' to have a 'Strength' attribute, and EITHER a 'Sword' attribute or an 'Axe' attribute, but not both?

I'm assuming the use of the 'choice' indicator, but I don't know how to structure the complexType to use both the 'choice' and the 'sequence' indicator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a simpleType for weapon like below code:

```
    <xs:simpleType name="weapon">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="axe" />
        <xs:enumeration value="sword" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: There is one complication, I already have defined a simple type for the attributes 'Sword' and 'Weapon' (They use the same simple type).

In reality, my attributes are <icon> and <model>. Both are of the simpleType 'filepath' and filepaths can not be enumerated as such.

I want the simpleType filepath to have its own restrictions on the string, but I want the owner element to only have one or the other. 

I guess I need to define whether or not the element uses a model or an icon in xsd, and either way it needs to have a filepath.

Comment: Hmm... Could you share with us your "weapon" type?

Comment: As mentioned above, the warrior / weapon scenario was just an example. At the moment, I intend to use the following filepath simpleType and validate the string with XML Schema regex (Pls excuse formatting). 


`<simpleType name="filepath">
  <restriction base="string">
    <xs:pattern value=""/><!--TODO How are we gonna validate this?-->
  </restriction>
</simpleType>`